# Install4j Change Logo

Tags: install4j

During installation, an install4j logo is displayed in the lower left corner. I would like to change that. In General Settings Tab Languages, I created a properties file and overwritten the messages there. But the logo is still displayed. Which message do I have to overwrite to change that?

[image: The Logo on the left side]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since install4j 7.x, go to Installer->Styles, edit the "Standard" style, select the "Watermark" component and set its "Text" property to the empty string.

[image]